# Wpf DatePicker validation error on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datepicker

I have a standard wpf datepicker box where the **SelectedDate** is bound:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="EffDatePicker" SelectedDate="{Binding EffectiveDate, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

When the page loads, the datepicker is getting highlighted with a red border, suggesting that the validation has failed, probably because the EffectiveDate is not set.

[image: Validation error!]

I can set the effective date on startup, but then I lose the built in "Select a date" watermark, which I'd like to keep. I can also set the TargetNullValue in the binding, but then I lose that watermark again.  I'm using OneWayToSource because the date is only ever set by the user, never through the model. Perhaps I'm using that incorrectly?

When the user selects a date, it does properly set the `EffectiveDate` property in the model and the error goes away.

I know I can set the validation error template to `{x:Null}` and *suppress* that red border from being shown, but that feels hacky.  I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298781/wpf-datepicker-validation-error-appears-when-binding-value-is-null), but it looks like that problem came from binding to **Text** instead of **SelectedDate**.

Can anyone suggest the right way to *fix* the validation error and not just hide it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own `ValidationRule` to use with `DatePicker`.

Let's say you have nullable `DateTime` property in your viewmodel, e.g.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {}

    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

And in your XAML you have

```
...
xmlns:rules="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.ValidationRules"
...
<DatePicker x:Name="EffDatePicker">
    <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
        <Binding Path="EffectiveDate" 
                 Mode="OneWayToSource" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <rules:DateRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
</DatePicker>
```

Then the following rule would the trick

```
namespace YourNameSpace.ValidationRules
{
    public class DateRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(value is DateTime || value == null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...actually, you could achieve same thing just by having `nullable` DateTime. But you got the point?

Comment: And you are correct! I keep forgetting that nullable exists-- I check things for null all the time, but never explicitly say it can be nulled. Thanks!

Comment: I need help understanding the signature of the ValidationResult(value is DateTime || value == null, null);

Comment: It's valid if value is typeof(DateTime) or null, since DateTime is nullable.

Comment: Mikko: Thank you for you reply.                                                         value is DateTime || value == null  will always evaluate to True. And the message on the Error Provider is saying Value'' could not be converted.I tried to overwrite the message by passing a customized one: ValidationResult(value is DateTime || value == null, "This is a customized Message"); but the old message still showing. Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe open a new question and link it here

Comment: I'm fairly new to stackoverflow. But someone will tag it as duplicate.